# How to make jQuery script refresh itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Explanation: Ajax will load content for a div "Content" without refreshing the page. If div "Content" is longer than 300px - hide "Soc_menu_l". The script runs absolutely OK only on page's refresh: if I try update div's height without refreshing the page - nothing happens. I check the heights of the div in Mozilla's inspector - the height is changed, but the script does not react to it. How can I make the script "watch" the height continuously and infinitely?

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#content').height() > 300) {
        $('.soc_menu_l').hide();
    }
});
```

Or maybe I should call this script each time after "Content"-div is loaded?

Comment: The code does not magically keep checking. You need to run the code after the content is updated.

Comment: I use jQuery buttons: $('#change1').click(function() {$('#content').css({"height":"600px"});
    });

Comment: or fire an event at the end of your click function and add an listener

Comment: @SethMcClaine since when did divs have onchange events?

Comment: Sorry, Do they not? Was thinking it was available on any element

Comment: @SethMcClaine Nope, only on [input, select, textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

Comment: ok... I retract that then, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**
Add Event listener:

```
$('#change1').click(function() {
  $('#content').css({"height":"600px"}); 
  $(window).fireEvent('change1');
});

$(window).addEventListener('change1', function() {
  if($('#content').height() > 300){
    $('.soc_menu_l').hide();  
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Option 1 with minor changes makes job ABSOLUTELY OK!